# Combine date and time in SQL Server in SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `From`  date in my table but I want to add fix time to it

I'm trying like this

```
select cast(FromDate as date) + cast('18:00:00' as time(3)) as StartDT 
from WsWmpLeaveReason
```

but this is causing an error:

> Operand data type date is invalid for add operator.

Comment: yes i'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(HOUR, 18, CAST(CAST(FromDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) as StartDT 
FROM
   WsWmpLeaveReason
```

See the [freely available, comprehensive SQL Server Books Online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.100).aspx) for more details on `DATEADD` and its options

Comment: "The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date." (or, from the documentation for `DATEADD`: "The return data type is the data type of the date argument, except for string literals")

Comment: it's giving this error : The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: arrrrgh! Of course - if it's a `DATE`, then it doesn't allow housr...... so you need to cast to `DATE` first to get zero time, then back to `DATETIME` so you can add hours..... thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: *SO* is so cool due to guys like you *@Damien_The_Unbeliever* and *@marc_s*

Answer (score 3):

Just as a different take on things, I'll wheel out my favourite `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` trick once again:

```
select DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',FromDate),'2001-01-01T18:00:00')
from WsWmpLeaveReason
```

This works by computing the (integral) number of days since 1st January 2001 to `FromDate`, and then adding that same number of (integral) days onto 18:00 on 1st January 2001. This, by deduction, must produce a date that has the same date as `FromDate`, but with the time portion fixed to 18:00.

Comment: +1 extra-smart - just not very intuitive and maintainable over time :-) Who'll figure this out in 6, 12 months from now? Better leave a good comment in your code! :-)

Comment: @marc_s - The first, second or third time you encounter it, it may not be too intuitive. But since it's my "go-to" pattern for date/time manipulation, anyone who's worked with me for any amount of time quickly learns the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `datetime` and addition:

```
select cast(cast(FromDate as date) as datetime) + cast('18:00:00' as time(3)) as StartDT 
from WsWmpLeaveReason;
```

If `FromDate` is already lacking a time component, you can just do:

```
select cast(FromDate as datetime) + cast('18:00:00' as time(3)) as StartDT 
from WsWmpLeaveReason;
```

You can add a `time` to a `datetime`, but not to a `date`.